# Is there a difference between using 2 slashes and using 1 slash when replacing one pattern by another in a string in bash?

Tags: bash, find-and-replace

Given the following strings in bash

```
original="a bird flew in my window"

old="a"

new="the"
```

the following, using 2 slashes after original

```
result=${original//$old/$new}
```

will make result="the bird flew in my window"

I've seen this syntax with 2 slashes in at least one book and also in

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142131/replace-a-word-with-another-in-bash

However the following with 1 slash also does the same

```
result=${original/$old/$new}
```

Are there cases where there is a difference between using 1 or 2 slashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `${parameter/pattern/string}`
>
> The *pattern* is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. *Parameter* is expanded and the longest match of *pattern* against its value is replaced with *string*. […] **If *pattern* begins with `/`, all matches of *pattern* are replaced with string. Normally only the first match is replaced.**

<sup>([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), emphasis mine)</sup>

Try with `original="a sparrow flew in my window"`. You will get `the sparrow flew in my window` or `the sptherrow flew in my window`. Your example did not show any difference because there is just one `a` in your expanded `$original`.